# Error en rating una pelicula - DRF

Tags: django, api, rest, djangorestframework

Estoy queriendo hacer una API que sea de reviews de peliculas. Ademas, tiene para hacer rating de las peliculas.

Pude hacer facilmente para listar y ver las peliculas pero el problema es cuando quiero crear el rating.

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
KeyError at /api/v1/rate/1/
'movie'
```

A continuación dejo los codigos de la view, url, serializer y model.

model.py:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
"""Movie rating model."""

movie = models.ForeignKey(
    Movie,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='rated_movie'
)

rating_user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='rating_user',
)

comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)
```

serializers.py:

```
class CreateMovieRatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Create movie rating serializer."""

rating = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
comments = serializers.CharField(required=False)

class Meta:
    """Meta class."""

    model = Rating
    fields = ('rating', 'comments')

def validate(self, data):
    """Verify rating hasn't been emitted before."""
    user = self.context['request'].user
    movie = self.context['movie']

    q = Rating.objects.filter(
        movie=movie,
        rating_user=user,
    )
    if q.exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Rating have already been emitted!')
    return data

def create(self, data):
    """Create rating."""
    Rating.objects.create(
        movie=self.context['movie'],
        rating_user=self.context['request'].user,
        **data
    )

    ride_avg = round(
        Rating.objects.filter(
            movie=self.context['movie']
        ).aggegate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg'],
        1
    )
    self.context['movie'].rating = ride_avg
    self.context['ride'].save()

    return self.context['movie']
```

El serializer use el mismo que se uso en el curso de django avanzado de la plataforma Platzi, solo cambie los valores correspondientes.

views.py:

```
class CreateRatingView(CreateAPIView):
"""Create rating view."""

queryset = Rating.objects.all()
serializer_class = CreateMovieRatingSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
path('rate/<int:pk>/', views.CreateRatingView.as_view()),
```

Me deja ver la vista y todo, lo de min y max value funciona y todo. El problema es cuando quiero hacer el rate sale el error anteriormente mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que hagas esto: self.context['movie'] tienes que verificar que el key exista en el context, por ejemplo:

```
if 'movie' in self.context:
    movie = self.context['movie']
```

Ya que si el key no existe en self.context entonces te lanzara la excepcion KeyError

Ahora con respecto a por que te sale el error, por favor comparte que estas mandando de body en tu request, para tu serializer CreateMovieRatingSerializer deberias de mandar algo asi:

```
{'rating': 5, 'comments': 'Mensaje'}
```

Y por lo que veo tu modelo Rating tiene un campo movie, creo que también necesitas pasarlo en tu serializer, ya que de caso contrario tu rating no va a tener relación a una Movie

Comment: Hola Kevin, como hago para ver el body del request?

Comment: El problema que estoy viendo es que no se pasa la pelicula por la url, ya que si pongo cualquier pk me sale para hacer el rating cuando deberia salir que no existe, alguna idea de como hacerlo?